# How to display data in archive page?

Tags: posts, taxonomy, archives, customization

I have a custom post type 'job'. I created a archive-job.php . How can I display 'post date', 'city', 'state' in my archive-job.php page?

1. Currently, my archive-job.php page displays a list of jobs that has 'title' and 'summary' only.
2. 'city' and 'state' is a taxonomy.
3. I use 'Formidable Pro' to create front-end job post form. (I guess this doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `the_terms` function in WP to display your term values in your archive page.

### Usage

```
the_terms( $id, $taxonomy, $before, $sep, $after );
```

### Parameters

- `$id` (int|req) -> Post ID. *Default: None*
- `$taxonomy` (str|req) -> Taxonomy name. *Default: None*
- `$before` (str|opt) -> Text to display before tags are displayed. *Default: Empty string*
- `$sep` (str|opt) -> Text or character to display between each tag link. *Default: ', '*
- `$after` (str|opt) -> Text to display after the last tag. *Default: Empty string*

[WP : Function Reference/`the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms)

Comment: Hi I insert this in content-job.php <?php get_the_terms( $id, $state ); ?> But nothing shows up.

Comment: Hi @jennifer,
`get_the_terms()` function doesn't echo results. you should assign it to a variable and then print the  results as you needed. or use `the_terms()` function instead.